# Next Greater Element

Tags: c++, arrays, loops

```
#include <iostream>
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int t;
    cin >> t;
    while (t--)
    {
        int n;
        cin >> n;
        int arr[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            cin >> arr[i];
        }
        stack<int>s;
        stack<int>q;
        for (int i = n - 1; i > 0; i--)
        {
            s.push(arr[i]);
        }
        while (!s.empty())
        {
            int a = s.top();
            s.pop();
            int flag = 0;
            while (!s.empty())
            {
                int p = s.top();
                if (a >= p)
                {
                    q.push(p);
                    s.pop();
                }
                else {
                    cout << p;
                    flag = 1;
                    break;
                }
                p = s.top();
            }
            if (flag == 0)
            {
                cout << -1;
            }
            while (!q.empty())
            {
                s.push(q.top());
                q.pop();
            }

        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Given an array, print the Next Greater Element (NGE) for every element. The Next greater Element for an element x is the first greater element on the right side of x in array. Elements for which no greater element exist, consider next greater element as -1.
Why is this code giving segmentation fault?

Comment: Possibly unrelated.     `int n;
    cin>>n;
    int arr[n];` is not legal C++. In C++ array bounds must be compile time constants, but in the code above `n` is a variable.

Comment: Replace `int arr[n];` with `vector<int> arr(n);` which at least is legal C++ and might fix the problem.

Comment: @J.Soumya Why are you using stacks? Will it be simpler to use just loops?

Comment: What is `#include<bits/stdc++.h>`? It is not a standard header

Comment: Using loops it will take more time I guess.

Answer (score 2):

Change this:

```
for (int i = n - 1; i > 0; i--)
```

to this:

```
for (int i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--)
```

since you want to push all elements to the stack.

After that, for this input:

```
1
3
1
2
3
```

I got the expected output:

```
23-1
```

Note: As @John said, `p = s.top();` does nothing, so it can safely be removed (since `p` is going to go out of scope anyway).

Answer (score 0):

```
p=s.top();
```

Crash here I suspect. No guarantee that `s` is not empty at that point.

The line of code has no effect (except maybe crashing the program) since `p` is a local variable about to go out of scope. It can be safely removed.

Comment: And . . ? :) I mean, I don't think that will give correct results, anyway. Although OP asks about where it crashes...

Comment: That line of code does nothing, since you are about to exit the scope where `p` is declared. You could write `p = 999;` and it would make no difference at all.

Comment: John I agree, but there is a fundamental problem in OP's code. Please see my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57131867/2411320). I mean yes that code you say has no effect, but is not what is causing the problem.

Comment: It is now giving correct results but how should I optimise it as it is giving TLE??

Answer (score 0):

After solving the issue in my previous [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57131867/2411320), one could based on @VladFromMoscow's comment, and use **loops** to achieve this, without using two additional data structures.

The strategy could be the following:

```
For every element `e` in the array
  Check if next element of `e` is greater than `e`
    If yes, print it
```

That implies the use of two for loops, where the first loop would scan the whole array. The second loop would scan the array from the next element of `e`, until the end of the array.

Note: You can skip the last element in the first loop, since it's guaranteed not to have any next element (thus no greater next element as well).

However, it might be that you need to store these greater elements, and for sure you could use a stack (LIFO Data Structure) for that, but I find it more natural to use a FIFO Data Structure, such as a queue. An array could also be used, for sure.

Notice that even in the case that you need to store the elements, with this loop-based approach, you use *one* additional data structures, not two (as in your code).

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
  int n;
  cin >> n;
  if(!n)
  {
    cout << "Array will be empty, exiting..\n";
    return 1;
  }
  int arr[n];
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
  {
    cin >> arr[i];
  }
  queue<int> q;
  // start 1st element until pre-last.
  for(int i = 0; i < n - 1; ++i)
  {
    // start from next element of i-th element, until last.
    for(int j = i + 1; j < n; ++j)
    {
      if(arr[j] > arr[i])
      {
        q.push(arr[j]);
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  while(!q.empty())
  {
    cout << q.front() << ", ";
    q.pop();
  }
  // last element of array does not have any next element
  cout << "-1\n";
  return 0;
}
```

Input:

> 3 1 2 3

Output:

> 2, 3, -1

Note: If you don't need to store the next greater elements, then simply print `arr[j]` instead of doing `q.push(arr[j]);`, and then `break` the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Solution in Python

```
a = [1, 5, 2, 9]

a.reverse()

if a == sorted(a):
    print("No")
else:
    for i in range(len(a)-1):
        if a[i] > a[i+1]:
            a[i], a[i+1] = a[i+1], a[i]
            break

a.reverse()
print(a)
```

Output : `[1, 5, 9, 2]`

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
// your code goes here
ios_base::sync_with_stdio(0);
cin.tie(0);
cout.tie(0);
int test;
cin >> test;
while(test--)
{
    int n;
    cin >> n ;
    vector<int>v(n);
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    cin >> v[i];
    vector<int>output(n,-1);
    stack<int>s;
    s.push(0);
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        while(!s.empty() && v[s.top()]<v[i])
        {
            output[s.top()]=v[i];
            s.pop();
        }
        s.push(i);
    }
    for(auto x:output)
    cout << x << " ";
    cout << "\n";
}
return 0;
}
```

---

SAMPLE INPUT :
1
4
4 5 2 25
SAMPLE OUTPUT:
5 25 25 -1

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).